# Postgres CASE expression ELSE clause affects performance even when clause 'true'

Tags: postgresql

Using PG 9.3 I have a report query that SELECTs phone call data.

If the current User is an 'admin', they can see *all* the calls.
Otherwise, the User can only see his own calls.

Hence we have (simplified)

```
create table phonecalls (phone_id int, destination varchar(100));
create table users (user_id int);
create table usergroups (user_id int, group_id int);
create table groups (group_id int, is_admin bool);
create table userphones (user_id int, phone_id int);
```

and the following permissions clause:

```
SELECT * FROM phonecalls
WHERE
CASE WHEN ( SELECT is_admin FROM users join usergroups using (user_id) join groups using (group_id) WHERE user_id = 1 )
THEN true
ELSE
   exists ( SELECT phone_id FROM userphones 
            WHERE user_id = 1 
            AND userphones.phone_id = phonecalls.phone_id )
END
```

When the database has many, many records in it, performance is an issue.

What I'm finding is, if the user with user_id 1 is an admin, the query speeds up if I remove the ELSE part of the permissions clause, i.e.

```
ELSE
   exists ( SELECT 1 )
END
```

But this seems to contradict the following statement from the Postgres documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-conditional.html

> A CASE expression does not evaluate any subexpressions that are not needed to determine the result.

If the User is an admin, the ELSE clause should have no effect on query execution time?
Am I misunderstanding?

**EDIT** Query plan output:

```
Seq Scan on phonecalls  (cost=139.44..421294.43 rows=5000 width=10) (actual time=0.071..5.598 rows=10000 loops=1)
  Filter: CASE WHEN $0 THEN true ELSE (alternatives: SubPlan 2 or hashed SubPlan 3) END
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=36.89..139.44 rows=1538 width=1) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=36.89..80.21 rows=128 width=5) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (groups.group_id = usergroups.group_id)
                ->  Seq Scan on groups  (cost=0.00..33.30 rows=2330 width=5) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                ->  Hash  (cost=36.75..36.75 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB
                      ->  Seq Scan on usergroups  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Filter: (user_id = 1)
          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..40.06 rows=12 width=4) (never executed)
                ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..40.00 rows=12 width=4) (never executed)
                      Filter: (user_id = 1)
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Seq Scan on userphones  (cost=0.00..42.10 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: ((user_id = 1) AND (phone_id = phonecalls.phone_id))
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Seq Scan on userphones userphones_1  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
          Filter: (user_id = 1)
Total runtime: 6.229 ms
```

**EDIT 2** Query Plan for 'SELECT 1' option

```
"Result  (cost=139.44..294.44 rows=10000 width=10) (actual time=0.044..3.713 rows=10000 loops=1)"
"  One-Time Filter: CASE WHEN $0 THEN true ELSE $1 END"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=36.89..139.44 rows=1538 width=1) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)"
"          ->  Hash Join  (cost=36.89..80.21 rows=128 width=5) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                Hash Cond: (groups.group_id = usergroups.group_id)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on groups  (cost=0.00..33.30 rows=2330 width=5) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=36.75..36.75 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on usergroups  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                            Filter: (user_id = 1)"
"          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..40.06 rows=12 width=4) (never executed)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..40.00 rows=12 width=4) (never executed)"
"                      Filter: (user_id = 1)"
"  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on phonecalls  (cost=0.00..155.00 rows=10000 width=10) (actual time=0.012..1.502 rows=10000 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 4.307 ms"
```

Comment: The 6ms seem quite fast - can you post the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)` for a _slow_ query?

Comment: Can you show the plan where you used `exists ( SELECT 1 )`? Perhaps the difference is in planning time.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is `Filter` vs. `One-Time Filter`.

In the first query, the condition in the `CASE` expression depends on `phonecalls.phone_id` from the sequential scan (even if that branch is never executed), so the filter will be applies to all 10000 result rows.

In the second query, the filter has to be evaluated only once; the query is run in an `InitPlan` that is executed before the main query is run.

These 10000 checks must make the difference.

Comment: so.. the InitPlan costs more time in the original query, even though strictly-speaking the subexpression is never evaluated?

Comment: It is not the cost of the never evaluated subexpression, but the (simple) expression that is evaluated for every row (because the complete expression is not independent of the table columns).

Answer (score 1):

If `Case` statement is in `select`/projection part then it does not have a considerable performance impact. if it is part of `order by` , `group by`, `where` or `join` a condition,  it might not use proper index and may cause performance issues

Comment: do you have a reference for that info?  Doco page I referenced doesn't stipulate